# Is sun.misc.Unsafe become public in JDK9?

Tags: java, java-9, sun

I just tried `JDK9` and found out that `sun.misc.Unsafe` is now containing not a native method, but delegates them to some `jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe`, for example:

```
@ForceInline
public int getInt(Object o, long offset) {
    return theInternalUnsafe.getInt(o, offset);
}
```

The latest, in turn, looks actually like the old `sun.misc.Unsafe`, but now the methods are annotated with some annotation:

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public native void putObject(Object o, long offset, Object x);
```

So, is it "safe" to use `Unsafe` starting JDK9? Is it a public official API now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good explanation:

> https://adtmag.com/blogs/watersworks/2015/08/java-9-hack.aspx
>
> What to do with sun.misc.Unsafe in Java 9? One side says it's simply
> an awful hack from the bad old days that should be gotten rid of; the
> other side says its heavy use is responsible for the rise of Java in
> the infrastructure space and popular tools still need it. The problem
> is, both sides are right.
> ...
>
> Writing on the OpenJDK mailing list, Reinhold proposed encapsulating
> unsupported, internal APIs, including sun.misc.Unsafe, within modules
> that define and use them. That proposal is now a formal Java
> Enhancement Proposals (JEP). Posted this week, JEP 260 ("Encapsulate
> Most Internal APIs") aims to "make most of the JDK's internal APIs
> inaccessible by default, but leave a few critical, widely used
> internal APIs accessible, until supported replacements exist for all
> or most of their functionality."

Short answer: you should NOT use it in any new application you're developing from scratch.

Comment: Shorter answer: you should not use it.

Comment: Don't deliberately use it yourself ... But don't panic if you happen to see it in some other code ;)

Answer (score 6):

The explanation by [@paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778748/1746118) is good enough to know whether to use it further or not.

***Long Answer ~ [JEP 260: Encapsulate Most Internal APIs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260)***

---

> Why did they decide over removing/deprecating the support of an API
>   used for long?

### Usefulness

In  *[The Modular JDK<sub>JEP 200</sub>](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/200)*, limiting access to *non-standard, unstable, and unsupported APIs* that are *internal implementation details of the JDK* by leveraging *[The Module System<sub>JEP 261</sub>](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)* **improves the integrity and security of the platform** since many of these internal APIs define privileged, security-sensitive operations. In the long run, **this change will reduce the costs borne by the maintainers** of the JDK itself and of libraries and applications that, knowingly or not, make use of these internal APIs.

---

> Are all the internal APIs planned to be encapsulated?

### Categories

The above specified JDK's internal APIs are divided into two broad categories:-

- *Non-critical internal APIs* which do not appear to be used by code outside of the JDK or are used by outside code merely for convenience..
- *Critical internal APIs* which provide critical functionality that would be difficult, if not impossible, to implement outside of the JDK itself (e.g., `sun.misc.Unsafe`).

---

> What if someone is migrating code that already makes use of `Unsafe`, but eventually plans to move away?

### *`sun.misc.Unsafe`*

Its one of those critical internal APIs that are not encapsulated in JDK 9, because supported replacements did not exist in JDK 8 when at the same time most of the other APIs are encapsulated or deprecated to be removed in future releases.

> Is sun.misc.Unsafe become public in JDK9?

- ***Usage***

  Currently to access the critical internal API's such as `Unsafe`, one needs to define a dependency on the `jdk.unsupported` module which is defined specifically for the purpose:

  ```
  module jdk.unsupported {
      exports sun.misc;
      opens sun.misc;
      ...
  }
  ```

➜ *As much as it could answer your question, you won't find this module [documented](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/overview-summary.html#JDK) even, probably to restrict consumers from making use of it and clearly a sign of avoiding it to make it "public".*

- **Migration**

  The functionality of many of the methods in the `Unsafe` class has been made available via *[Variable Handles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) <sub>JEP 193</sub>*.